# Do conditional statements introduce block scope for variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a minor problem with a JavaScript snippet that I hope you can help me solving it.

```
var z=0;

function xyz() { 
    if (!z) {
        z+=5;
        var h=15; // The problem resides here
    }
    else { 
        var f=h+7;
        alert(f);
         }
    z++;
    return z;    
}
```

When I registered this function to a click event handler on a button element, I was expecting to see by the second iteration of function execution an alert message displaying

```
22
```

What I had was a **NaN** message indicating that the variable **h** wasn't defined despite the explicit declaration statement within the **if** branch but when I omitted the **var** keyword, suddenly the function behaved :)

It's really puzzling for me as I am pretty sure that JS doesn't natively support block scoping except when using the **let** keyword introduced by Mozilla browsers. I am also darn sure that declaring variables using the var keyword creates local scope for them and therefore they become exclusively accessible within the function in which they are defined.

So, why on the world I have to declare **h** as a global variable for the function to work?

Any help would be very appreciated as I am new to Web Design and I am coming from  graphic design background.

Note: Actually,this was not the real life problem that I faced during coding. I was trying to create a ticker that updates every 10 seconds automatically using the **setInterval()** method and then suppressing it when the user browses the headlines manually and when he's done, the script takes over once again.

I thought that a more generic and simple example is more suitable to explain the solution without getting into the details of the methods/properties used.

=======

## UPDATE

I think I got it now. Functions don't have memories and thus can't remember values generated from previous calls. What I was doing actually is storing the value generated from the first call in a global variable that can be accessed in future calls. But I'm wondering is there any elegant way to achieve the same result other than using global variables?

Answer (score 6):

No. In fact all your local variables are initialized at the beginning of your function. Your example code will be executed like this:

```
function xyz() { 
    var h;
    var f;
    if (!z) {
        z+=5;
        h=15;
    }
    else { 
        f=h+7;
        alert(f);
         }
    z++;
    return z;    
}
```

You get `NaN` because in `f=h+7` `h` is declared but it's value is *undefined*.

There is a more *elegant* way: using objects. There are may ways you can create objects, I use the most compact method here:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.z = 0;
    // it's safer to initialize all your variables (even if you dn't use the initial value)
    this.h = 0;
    this.f = 0;

    this.xyz = function () {
        if (!this.z) {
            this.z += 5;
            this.h = 15;
        } else { 
            this.f = this.h + 7;
            alert(this.f);
        }
        this.z++;
        return this.z;    
    }
}

var o = new MyObject();
o.xyz();
o.xyz();
```

There are many-many docs about OOP in JS if you are interested.

Comment: Explanation for the OP: The value of `h` is `undefined` because the if-branch did not execute, so that the assignment `h = 15` didn't occur.

Comment: @Sime> Actually the `z` variable is initialized and set to zero outside the function in the global scope. Since it's set to zero, the function must enter the first branch of the `if` statement in the first iteration.

Comment: @vbence Explain to me why it's working in the global scope and not the local one?   Please note that the function must visit the 1st branch of the `if` statement and consequently overwriting the initial value of the variable `z` and declaring the `h` variable

Comment: @ادي عبد الهادي Each function call defines a new set of local variables. When the function is called for the 1. time, `h` is indeed set to 15. However, when the function is called for the 2. time, the `h` local variable is not set to 15 which means that its initial `undefined` value is used.

Comment: @Šime Vidas Thanks for your answer. I think I got it now. Functions don't have memories and thus can't remember values generated from previous calls. What I was doing actually is storing the value generated from the first call in a global variable that can be accessed in future calls. But I'm wondering is there any elegant way to achieve the same result other than using global variables?

Comment: @ادي عبد الهادي Yes, there is indeed a more elegant way. See the OOPexample at the end of my answer.

Comment: @vbence thanks for your answer. It's working but I don't why I have to use the inline registration model to make it work. No matter how hard I tried to use either the W3C or traditional model to add an event listener to the button, it won't work. Any clue?

Comment: @ادي عبد الهادي I think you should start a new question with that problem. It concerns the event model, not really JS.

Comment: @ادي عبد الهادي Also, cosider voting up the answers you find useful, or even accept the best one. - This is how SO works :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope, only functions have a local scope.  Do *not* put anything in global scope unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: @Šime_Vidas: @vbence gave a more detailed answer -- I just answer the question in the title.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The OP asks two different questions - one in the title and one in the question body. You answered on of those questions, which makes your answer valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use closures to get the result (I think) you want, e.g.

```
var xyz = (function() {
  var z = 0;
  var h;

  return function() { 
    var f;

    if (!z) {
      z += 5;
      h = 15;

    } else { 
      f = h + 7;
      alert(f);
    }
    return ++z;
  }
})();
```

the first time nothing is shown, after that 22 is always shown and z increments 6, 7, 8, and so on.

-- 
Rob

Comment: Thanks Rob for your valuable answer. It works like a charm but the concept of closures is bit advanced for me. Every time I read on the subject, I get frustrated but sooner or later I will manage to get my head around it.    Just one simple question, do I have to initialize variables like you did with `h` and `f` for functions or it's okay to use them out of the box?